# Centering my linear layout in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve this positioning:

[image]

Where I have two rows of EditText and TextView next to each other.

The version textview is anchored to the bottom of the screen, but takes up the entire width and the text is centered.

My current layout file is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.mp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

     <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                    android:layout_width="250dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NEW"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:textSize="10pt" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext2"
                    android:layout_width="250dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NEW"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:textSize="10pt" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:gravity="bottom">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Version 1.0"
                    android:textColor="#444444"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:textSize="10pt" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the two rows of EditText and TextView are positioned past the middle of the screen and the Version textview is immediately below the two rows of EditText and TextView instead of anchored at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a `RelativeLayout` for the root layout and use the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the "version". Then wrap the other `Views` in a `LinearLayout`. Something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="NEW"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textSize="10pt" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NEW"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textSize="10pt" />
          </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Version 1.0"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textSize="10pt"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't had a chance to really test it but this should get you pretty close. I wrapped the two sets of `Views` in the center in a `LinearLayout` then gave each their own `LinearLayout` so they can make use of `weight` (which you can adjust to your needs). The parent `LinearLayout` is centered vertical so that those 4 `Views` will be centered the way I believe you want.

Comment: Isn't it "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" message in the xml file without xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" attribute?

Comment: @codeMagic How do I move the linearlayouts up a bit? The centering seems to push everything far too low. It seems like it's because the it's aligning the top of the first linearlayout to the center of the screen instead of using the center of both the linearlayouts

Comment: @user3479463 on my screen it seems to be centering it. Anyway you can use a little bit of `android:layout_marginBottom="some dp"` to move it up. Where some dp" is an int like "20dp". But, the way it is, it would be aligning the center of the whole parent `LinearLayout`

Comment: @user3479463 Try using android:layout_centerInParent="true" instead of android:layout_centerVertical="true" for the outer LinearLayout. It should center the layout on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:gravity="center">//hope this will work for you

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alltextfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"`enter code here`
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alltextfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read the question carefully! (This avoids you downvotes)